# why not showing the phonegap icons in phonegap2.0 version while creating new project in xcode4.3

Tags: cordova, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

I am new to iphone develop and phonegap also. Now i installed phonegap2.0 version im my lion mac Xcode4.3. now i seen the phonegap icon didn't show when i create a new project in xcode4.3. But the phonegap icon showing in phonegap1.5.
I have attach Screen Short.

this screen short is phonegap2.0

[image]

this screen short is phonegap1.5
  IS this any problem to developing any app using this phonegap?[image].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Recently, I downloaded phone gap version 2.0.0 and installed it on Mac OSX 10.7.1 with Xcode version 4.2. I too got the same problem, (Actually its not a problem at all). You can create PhoneGap application using terminal :-) Just confirmed it here :*

*Source*

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap

*OR if we still could see something like in the second screen, I would also like to know :]*

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will check out in chat room.

Comment: Hi. I want some help from you. I hope am not disturbing you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the late response. If it is about phone gap, I am totally sorry, I am all struck there!

Comment: Hi good morning. It is ok. Did you finish to install phonegap2.0?. NOw are you working in phonegap2.0 in Xcode4.2?.

Comment: Sorry for the disturb. Do you now how to create Uicontorls in iphone using phonegap2.0?. (Uicontorls like: Tabbar, Button, Textview, ActionSheet like these controls)

Comment: I just know the gist. There are some API for each UIControl in js format I believe. You have to include it in the project and use it on respective .html file :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. you mean Camera,contact,file,Accelerometer these api's?. I have done these api's in my xcode. It was working perfectly. But now i want button, Textfield, Tabbar, these controls.

Comment: http://nathancampos.me/post/23831039066/how-to-setup-and-use-nativecontrols-in-phonegap Try this.. It didn’t work for me though.. You could try it out!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16906/discussion-between-gopinath-m-and-nina)

Answer (score 1):

we meet again! ^^

It seems that it is normal that there's no icon for the version 2.0.0 of phonegap...

In fact, according to the online doc ( http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS ), the XCode project file is created with the terminal (`Terminal.app`).

Once this project file is created, you can open it with XCode and use the development tool the same as if you were developping with phonegap version 1.5.0.

Try to follow the steps described in the online doc. If you're still having issues, you can ask me questions ^^.

Hope this information helps :)

Comment: I tried phonegap1.5.0 in snow leopard under your instruction. It is working perfectly. But i want to work in phonegap2.0.0.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for 1.5.0 ^^. I know it would be better to use the lattest version of phonegap :P

Comment: Hi Littm. Do you have any idea on this issue? Looking forward your great help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.I am waiting for yuor updating.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16589/discussion-between-littm-and-gopinath-m)

Comment: Hi Littm. How are you. Have a great day.

Comment: Hi littm. Sorry for the disturb. If you free come to chat.